# MySQL Order of records in table

Tags: mysql

I have a very large staging table that I want to process a few rows at a time into an indexed table.

As the time to write indexes results in longer than desired locks on the target table I usually do this a few 100k rows at a time. I pick the rows using order by a unique column as well as Limit and Offset to pick a value to repeatedly churn away on the staging table.

```
SELECT unique_id INTO @cut_off FROM staging_X ORDER BY unique_id;

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO my_indexed_table ([columns])
  SELECT columns FROM staging_X where unique_id <= @cut_off;

DELETE FROM my_indexed_table WHERE unique_id <= @cut_off;

COMMIT;
```

I've done this for a couple of tables successfully, but am now faced with the largest table in my list. This one has more than 100 million rows.  It is created by Apache Spark, so I have no control over setting up partitions or anything.

I've been wondering if I can just use LIMIT with a constant value on both the INSERT and DELETE queries without trying to sort the data. But I cannot find anything that states that the rows will be returned in a reliably repeatable order.

For reference I am using MySQL 5.7 and INNODB tables.

**Update**

On request the data is something like this:

- uuid - Text
- timestamp1 - Bigint - unixtime
- timestmap2 - Bigint - unixtime
- timestmap3 - Bigint - unixtime
- timestmap4 - Bigint - unixtime
- url - Text
- metric1 - Int
- metric2 - Int

There are about 30 million rows per day and I can only process this weekly. I can throttle the provision of the data create multiple tables (I cannot create partitions) with a limited row count each but ideally, I'd just like to be able to reliably get the first N rows, insert them elsewhere and delete them, without trying to sort the data.

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to do exactly ?(With data samples) , maybe there's an easier way of doing this.

Comment: Yes, data samples would be good.